# Deleting Parts of a 3D object

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender. I bought a 3D object to import into Photoshop CC. But, when I did, it came with parts I didn't want. So, I imported the OBJ file into Blender.

I've been able to hide those elements, but when I export as an OBJ and import it into Photoshop the unwanted elements are still there.

Can someone tell me how to get rid of the unwanted parts and just export the parts of the model I want?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. You might need to tell us a little more about this object, before anyone can give you a definitive answer. Please use the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/135595/edit) below your question and add at least one [screenshot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) that might help us understand of the object in Blender that might help us understand what we're dealing with.

Comment: Hiding elements does not delete them from the object, it just makes them invisible to facilitate editing. You need to select the objects or vertices or faces you want to get rid of and hit the Delete key.

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out. I select an object by clicking on its layer on the right. Then I go to Delete on the left and that *really* deletes it. I've been able to bring it into Photoshop. I think the Blender interface is what tripped me up. Thanks for giving me a push!!!!